# ActiveMQ, Camel, Spring, simple route not working

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am having some trouble with a simple camel route that should be grabbing a message from an ActiveMQ topic that I have and then printing out the contents of the messages to the console through the use of log.

Right now all that it is is the camel-context.xml, and a java class that is producing the topic in ActiveMQ and adding a simple string message to the queue. I am using the ActiveMQ interface to check to see if the topic is being created, and it is, but my message is not being added to the topic nor is it being routed through the camel route. Running main I can get the output of my sys out to the console, and I see that 1 message is "enqueued" and 1 message is "dequeued" in the activemq interface. I just do not get any output to the console from the "log message" in my route.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated since I am new to all 3 of these technologies, and I just want to get this simple "Hello World" working.

Thank you! The two files are found below:

After further testing I think that it just has something to do with the way that I am trying to log the contents of the message, because I know that it is picking up my camel route because I added a second topic and told the camel route to route the messages to it like the following:

to uri="activemq:topic:My.SecondTestTopic"

and I am able to see if being redirected to that queue in the activeMQ interface.

---

### TestMessageProducer.java

```
package com.backend;

import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class TestMessageProducer {

 private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();


        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Topic topic = session.createTopic("My.TestTopic");

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

        message.setText("THIS IS A TEST TEXT MESSAGE BEING SENT TO THE TOPIC AND HOPEFULLY BEING PICKED UP BY THE" +
                "CAMEL ROUTE");

        producer.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");

        connection.close();
    }
```

}

---

### Camel-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<spring:beans xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:alch="http://service.alchemy.kobie.com/"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<!-- load properties -->
<spring:bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <spring:property name="locations" value="file:backend.properties" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="properties"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <spring:property name="location" value="file:backend.properties" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <spring:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?useLocalHost=true" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <spring:property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <spring:property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <spring:property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="jmsConfig" 
    class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <spring:property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <spring:property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <spring:property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="activemq" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <spring:property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
</spring:bean>


<!-- camel configuration -->

 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:topic:My.TestTopic"/>
  <log message="Output of message from Queue: ${in.body}"/>
  <to uri="activemq:topic:My.SecondTestTopic" />
</route>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate post of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714651/camel-routing-xml-with-jms-activemq

Answer (score 1):

And you have started the Camel application first. Eg as you send non persistent messages to a topic. And if there is no active subscribers when sending, then the messages is not received by anybody. You may want to use persistent durable topic instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are creating two seperate instances of an ActiveMQ broker. Can you update your **TestMessageProducer** to use the URL *tcp://localhost:61616* ? Also, can you use jconsole to check the topic activity in the activemq instance on both VMs ?

**=== UPDATE ===**

I missed the bit about you verifying that the 2nd topic did receive the message, so your route is working.... Must be the logger. If you have the camel source code in your IDE, you could turn the debugger on and place a break point on

```
org.apache.camel.component.log.LogProducer
    .process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback)
```

to see what happens and if it is called. Which logging package do you have configured ?

Comment: I just changed the URL that I am using and will check it out now. I am not sure how to use jconsole though, I have never used it before.

Comment: Changing the URL it still runs and posts a message to the topic, and then it also reroutes it to the second topic so I can see that it is still working. I just cannot seem to get it to log out to the console still.

Comment: Perhaps your logger configuration in camel is funky. You could try setting it log at **ERROR** like this:   <log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Output of message from Queue: ${in.body}"/>

Comment: Hmmm thank you for the suggestion but that did not work. I think it may be just that I am missing some sort of setting in camel I don't know. Being this new to it I do not know how logging really works with camel I just have seen people in sample code try to log things like I have it set up.